# LilyPond: Can a double barline follow a multi-measure rest?

Tags: lilypond

I have a multi-measure rest at the end of a piece, and I cannot get a final "|." barline to print. The regular single barline is used instead.

Minimal example:

```
\score {
  \new Staff <<
    \compressFullBarRests
    R1*62
    \bar "|."
  >>
}
```

I'm using version 2.16; the problem exists with 2.17 as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't have anything to do with multi-measure rests.  It doesn't work because you had used `<< >>` (which indicate simultaneous music) instead of `{ }` (which indicate sequential music). With `<< >>`, all three commands (`\compressFullBarRests`, `R1*62` and `\bar "|."`) are processed simultaneously, which means that `\bar "|."` takes place at moment 0 (at the very beginning of music), *not after* rests.  This will work:

```
\score {
  \new Staff {
    \compressFullBarRests
    R1*62
    \bar "|."
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This does not seem to have anything to do with the multi-measure rest - the `|.` bar is not printed even if you use a note instead of the multi-measure rest.

Not sure why, but this seems to do the job:

```
melody =
{
  R1*62
  \bar "|."
}

\score {
  <<
    \compressFullBarRests
    \new Voice = "one" { \autoBeamOff \melody }
  >>
}
```

Comment: That does indeed work! Note that `\autoBeamOff` and the new `Voice` aren't specifically required to fix the problem, but of course are good to have in many scores.